# SQL Script for Counting Records based on specific criteria and returning the Counts

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I'm Trying to count records with specific criteria in my Database to ultimately produce some statistical reports.

```
My Tables and Fields are:
1- Import Table:bed_ID, unit_ID, mrn, acccount_num, sex, service_ID
2- Beds: bed_ID, unit_ID, bed_type_ID
3- Bed_Type: bed_type_ID, bed_type_description
4- Unit: unit_ID, unit_common_name, program_ID, total_beds...other fields that don't apply.
5- Service: service_ID, service_common_name, program_ID
6- Program: program_ID, program_common_name
```

I want to create a query that will give me a count of each Bed_Type_Description for each Unit. I also want to get each units total beds and calculate beds available but I'm sure I can figure that out if I get help with this part.

```
Unit  Regular_Bed   Escalation_Bed   Transfer_Bed   Bassinet
-------------------------------------------------------------
Unit1    10               4                2           2
Unit2    12               2                2           0
etc...
etc...
```

This is what I have, but its only related to one specific Unit:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(dw_test.dbo.Bed_Type.bed_type_description) as 'Total Number of Beds'
FROM 
    dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board,
    --dw_test.dbo.Unit,
    dw_test.dbo.Beds, 
    dw_test.dbo.Bed_Type
WHERE 
    dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board.bed_ID = dw_test.dbo.Beds.bed_ID
--AND
--  dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board.unit_ID =     dw_test.dbo.Unit.unit_ID
AND 
    dw_test.dbo.Beds.bed_type_ID = dw_test.dbo.Bed_Type.bed_type_ID
AND 
    dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board.unit_ID = 'KA2MED'
AND 
    dw_test.dbo.Bed_Type.bed_type_description = 'Regular';
```

You'll notice a couple lines related to Unit that are commented out.  With these commented out I get a returned value of '5' records which is correct.  If i remove the commenting to include these lines it returns a value of '0' which makes no sense to me. If someone can explain this to me that'd be great as well.
My SQL is quite rusty, its been a while. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks again in advance for all your help.

Comment: I think I may have begun to find the solution.  This is where I'm at so far, the returned value Lists each unit with the corresponding # of total beds.                                                                                                   Select 
 dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board.unit_ID,
 count(*) as '# of Beds by Unit'
from 
 dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board
group by 
 dw_test.dbo.MediTechReport_Bed_Board.unit_ID
order by 
 COUNT(*);                                                                                                Need to organize by Bed Type.

Comment: When I try to incorporate the Bed_Type it doesn't work.  Also why would i get different numbers just by adding 1 additional table to the From clause?

Comment: Should I add a Union at the end to allow my scrip to build on itself and give me the outputs that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select t.bed_type_description, COUNT(t.bed_type_description) as 'Total Number Of Beds' 
from import As I inner join Beds as b on i.bed_Id = b.bed_Id 
inner join Unit as u on i.unit_Id = u.unit_Id 
inner join Bed_Type as t on b.bed_type_Id = t.bed_type_Id 
where u.unit_Id = 'KA2MED'
group by t.bed_type_description
```

Comment: That was great, thanks so much for the help with this.